# Stop robot car when it detects object with ultrasound sensor (C++)

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, robotics

Recently I've been trying to make my robot stops when it detects an obstacle in front of it. The situation is next: when I detect an object the car stops and that's OK, but when the object is gone the car doesn't continue to move to its final destination. Instead of doing this, the car should travel from point A to point B for 10 seconds ( 10 seconds is just an example, the time is different each movement) and when it will detect an object it should stop and wait until the object is gone, afterward it has to continue to its final destination (Point B).

I have an idea to count the time while the robot is not moving and add that time to time needed to reach the final point. But I'm struggling with that.

Here's the code:

```
int measureDistance()
{
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        cout << "Initialization problem - measureDistance() " << endl;

    Sonar sonar;
    sonar.init(trigger, echo);

    int distance = 0;

    distance = sonar.distance(30000);
    sleep_for(nanoseconds(10));

    return distance;
}

bool checkForObstacles() 
{
    wiringPiSetup();

    // Controlling the motors from here
    softPwmCreate(0, 0, 255);
    softPwmCreate(4, 0, 255);

    constexpr int MIN_DISTANCE = 20;

    int distance = measureDistance();
    cout << "Distance: " << distance << endl;

    if (distance >= MIN_DISTANCE)
        return false;

    softPwmWrite(0, LOW);
    softPwmWrite(4, LOW);

    while(distance < MIN_DISTANCE) 
    {
        delay(10); // re-measure after 10ms. Adjust to what you prefer
        distance = measureDistance();
        cout << "Measuring: " << distance << "cm" << endl;
    }


    return false;
}

void move(int t)
{
        // Pins where the motors are connected
    int ena = 0;
    int in1 = 2;
    int in2 = 3;

    int enb = 4;
    int in3 = 5;
    int in4 = 6;
    // Pins setup
    wiringPiSetup ();

    softPwmCreate(ena, 0, 255);
    pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);

    softPwmCreate(enb, 0, 255);
    pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

    // Control
    softPwmWrite(ena, 50);
    digitalWrite(in1, 1);
    digitalWrite(in2, 0);

    softPwmWrite(enb, 50);
    digitalWrite(in3, 1);
    digitalWrite(in4, 0);

    cout << "TIME: " << t << endl;
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while(true) 
    {
        auto now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(now-start).count();

        cout << "ELAPSED: " << elapsed << endl;

        int remaining = t - (int) elapsed;

        cout << "REMAINING: " << remaining << "ms" << endl;
        if (remaining < 0)
            break;

        if (checkForObstacles())
        {
            continue;
        }   

        delay(min(remaining, 25)); // replace 25 with how often you want to check the distance
    }

    softPwmWrite(ena, LOW);
    softPwmWrite(enb, LOW);
    delay(200);
}
```

**To resume: While the car is moving if I put an obstacle in front of it stops, but when I remove the obstacle the program ends - the car is not moving after that.** **This shouldn't be happening.**

P.S: Everything is running on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: checkForObstacles() never seems to return true, did you want to check for !checkForObstacles() instead?

Comment: @bdbdbd I just want to check if there's an obstacle to stop and when it's not to continue.

Comment: Question improvement suggestion: Make a bulleted list of requirements. What should happen in different situations. Also make a list of deviations.

Comment: `if (checkForObstacles()) { continue; }` is basically unreachable code since it will never be true

Comment: @bdbdbd You're right. What changes should I make?

Comment: I'll have a look at it in a few minutes, but I don't have a Raspberry Pi and sensors and such to test anything. First thing that doesn't seem right though is calling `wiringPiSetup()` all the time. It's used to initialize the wiring so it should happen once in the beginning, but you call it in two functions, which also get called several times within loops. I don't have experience with wiringPi but it doesn't seem right to call it more than once.

Comment: @bdbdbd I'm calling it once for initializing the sensor pins and then for the motors pins. The problem is handling the time. I'm looking forward to finding a solution to this.

Comment: Show the code block where the `move` function is called

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz I just pass the time in milliseconds

```
int main()
{
 int t = 8000;
 
 move(t);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Dawid Javier's point is that you have a big move() funtion that you actually never call once.
Edit: ah you didn't include your main where you call it :)

Comment: That might be the problem, when you `break` the `while` loop inside `move` because you have elapsed all of your time this allows `move` to finish, hence making `main` finish and thus finishing your program.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz So, how to fix the problem I encounter?

Comment: The problem you encounter can't be fixed outright because there's a logic inconsistency between your question, what's happening to you and that you use time to measure distance. For example, no matter how many correct answers are given. The fact will remain that the robot wouldn't move after removing the obstacle because time might have fully elapsed. At the best, you'll get partial answers, and rewrites of your code that maybe won't satisfy you or others and get downvoted. Let's see if I can write an answer free of ambiguity.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz You're free to write anything. If it doesn't work it's not a big deal. You've mentioned: "The fact will remain that the robot wouldn't move after removing the obstacle because time might have fully elapsed". Maybe if start a timer when the robot stops and add that time to the remaining time will fix the problem?

Comment: Also, what is point B exactly? Since you use time, then it can be any point, depending on time and speed. More importantly, if you place an obstacle and then remove it, point B changes because you spent time waiting for the obstacle to be lifted. So, a huge question that needs to be addressed is how to unambiguously get to point B. This can be done by keeping track of how much distance the robot moves at every step, and when the traveled distance is at some predetermined threshold then you've reached point B. Now if you put and lift an obstacle you would still get to point B correctly.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz Point B is where the robot should get to. The time (distance) between A and B is fixed.

Comment: Let me ask something else, does `checkForObstacles` stops the motors with `softPwmWrite`? Because if it does then you need to start them back again right after the `if (checkForObstacle)...` which by the way you can just replace that `if` by `checkForObstacle();`

Comment: If you start a timer when your robot stops and add it to the total time will correct an issue. But maybe not the whole thing. Try it and see what happens, I'll be around.

Comment: Yes, if there’s an obstacle in checkForObstacle() I turn off the motors. But I think that doesn’t affect it, the major problem is that remaining time flies when robot stops. That’s the problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Javier Silva Ortíz I don’t know how to make that. I need help

Comment: Dawid, let's focus first on correctly stopping and starting the motors. Divide and conquer my friend. You can always put some big time 60000, a minute to test motor functionality. So, `softPwmWrite(ena, LOW)` and `softPwmWrite(enb, LOW)` start the motors? If so, then move those lines right before the `delay(min(remaining, 25));` line in the `while` loop and see what happens.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz `softPwmWrite(ena, LOW) and softPwmWrite(enb, LOW)` stop the motors. I've tried to start them with changing LOW to HIGH, but nothing changed.

Comment: See why we need to tackle problems as small sets rather than a big thing. We could have wasted hours with a good solution, and then find out it didn't worked because the motors never went back on again. All right, I own one RB 3 B+ but only used once and was for an FM radio, so I don't know too much about them. Honestly, I think you should erase everything and start over, one thing at a time.  First figure out how to start and stop the motors. Then make the bot move for a while and stop its motors for another while and start them again. After that you should incorporate obstacle detection.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz I'm familiar with that. I've done that million times.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of pseudo-code because I don't know how your robot and wiringPi work exactly but I hope this code flow helps you in the right track:
measureDistance seemed pretty useless so I removed it (and it called the initialisation every time for some reason).
In your main you should set up all the pin stuff and sonar, then in an infinite loop you sleep for a bit, check obstacles, if there are none, you move, otherwise skip the moving part.

```
int main()
{
    // only initialize everything once, in your main
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        return -1;

    Sonar sonar;
    sonar.init(trigger, echo); // declare these somewhere first, I don't know the values

    while(1){
        sleep_for(nanoseconds(10)); // or delay(200) or whatever
        // if there are obstacles skip the move() part and go back to sleeping
        // or delay again, and try again
        if (checkForObstacles(sonar))
            continue;
        // No obstacle = move
        move();
    }
}

// this is only responsible for checking obstacles, no pin writing and moving happening
bool checkForObstacles(Sonar sonar) // pass in a reference to sonar
{
    constexpr int MIN_DISTANCE = 20;

    int distance = sonar.distance(30000);
    cout << "Distance: " << distance << endl;

    if (distance >= MIN_DISTANCE)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void move() {
    /*
    *  only move logic goes here
    * like the digitalWrites
    */
}
```

Comment: But what about time? The time is very important to move the robot from point A to point B.

Comment: @Dawid why? I'm pretty sure it can move without a sense of time first. I would focus on making it stop or move whenever there's an obstacle first, then worry about time. And the logic you have in place there at the moment seems pretty good already: stop moving if remaining time < 0. You could consider using that to break out of the while loop in your main and getting rid of the one in your move()

Comment: At the moment your code is all over the place and it doesn't do what the names claim. For example why are there pinWrites and other move logic in a obstacle detection function? Try making a function do one thing only, and making it do it well

Comment: It works like this: https://pastebin.com/rmFaHkBE

But this is not the point. My idea is to make the vehicle travel from point A to point B (the distance it's measured in time in my case) and when you put an obstacle while it's moving, the vehicle needs to stop and wait until the obstacle is removed and continue to its final destination.

That's the problem I have.